# CSS: Why doesn't calc(contain * 0.66) work?

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image, responsive-images, background-size

I have two layered background images that need to be sized with `contain` in order to display correctly at all responsive breakpoints.

When I was specifying `background-size` using **percentages** I found that the images were getting clipped by the div bounds at some breakpoints. So I switched to using `contain` instead of `%`. This fixed the clipping.

*However*, I also want to scale down these background images to be *smaller than 100%* of the `contain` value.

Unfortunately, `background-size: calc(contain * 0.66)` doesn't appear to work.

How else can I approach this?

(I don't think adding white space within the image files themselves can be a solution, because their white space also needs to be *responsive* - one image occupies the *upper left*, and the other the *bottom right* of the div's background area. The div's width-height ratio and area vary considerably depending on the browser window's size.)

Comment: [As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) : The calc() CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. It can be used with <length>, <frequency>, <angle>, <time>, <percentage>, <number>, or <integer> values.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to add calculation based on non-numeric value `contain`. But a very common work-around is to use pseudo element to mimic background image. Then you'll have better control to the dimensions of the pseudo element, here's an example:

> You may try to resize the container on the botton left corner to see the effect

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: gray;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div::before {
  /* the maximum size of the background-image */
  width: 66%;
  height: 66%;
  
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3D(-50%, -50%, -1px);
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/640/480) center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. to add a second image, would a second `div` be required? Or can a second background be added within the same `div::before`?

Comment: Because of `::before` is used now, you may use `::after` if you want a second background image using the same technique.